# foreach on Request.Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I'm attempting upload multiple files in ASP.NET MVC and I have this simple foreach loop in my controller

```
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase f in Request.Files)
{
    if (f.ContentLength > 0)
        FileUpload(f);
}
```

The previous code generates this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'.
```

What I don't understand is why Request.Files[1] returns an HttpPostedFileBase but when it's iterated over, it returns strings (presumably the file names).

Note: I know this can be solved with a for loop.
Also, I tried using HttpPostedFile, with the same error.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The enumerator on the `HttpFileCollection` returns the keys (names) of the files, not the `HttpPostedFileBase` objects.  Once you get the key, use the `Item` (`[]`) property with the key (filename) to get the `HttpPostedFileBase` object.

```
foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have it return an HttpPostedFile instead?

Comment: Not that I know of.  It derives from NameObjectCollectionBase and the enumerator for that class iterates over the keys.

Comment: The compiler throws an error for me and wants me to use `HttpPostedFileBase` instead of `HttpPostedFile`.

Comment: @tvanfosson in my case fileName always becomes "Image", but when I say Request.Files[0].FileName it gives the correct name any idea? I'm using MVC5.

Comment: @Geethanga - the "name" that is the key is the name on the HTML file input tag, it's not the name of the file that is uploaded.

Comment: I'd caution anyone using this answer that this was a problem for us on iOS because the "take photo" feature names every file "image.jpg." I'd recommend @harvey 's answer below.

Comment: @tvanfosson in my case its saving first file xtimes the x number of files uploaded

Answer (score 40):

With my tab HTML is:

```
<input class="valid" id="file" name="file" multiple="" type="file">
```

Request.Files will have duplicate name in array. So you should solve like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++ ){
    HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload = Request.Files[i];
```

Comment: This one worked better for me than the answer because, as their html points out, it allows for multiple files in the same file input.

Comment: This is the correct answer as you should be able to get the filename with `file.FileName`. If you do it with `foreach` and have duplicate names the first file will be saved multiple times

Answer (score 15):

We can use LINQ to do this and still use foreach as asked:

```
var files = Enumerable.Range(0, Request.Files.Count)
    .Select(i => Request.Files[i]);

foreach (var file in files)
{
    // file.FileName
}
```

As @tvanfosson said, the enumerator returns the file names as strings, not the `HttpPostedFileBase`. This method `HttpPostedFileBase this[string name]` returns the object we want. If `HttpFileCollectionBase` implemented `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` then we could do the foreach normally. However, it implements a non-generic `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Super  :-) :-). Working Fine

Answer (score 6):

You might try iterating the strings and casting them to HttpPostedFile instead, like this:

```
foreach (string file in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFile hFile = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFile;
        if (hFile.ContentLength > 0)
            FileUpload(hFile);
    }
```

Comment: cannot implicitly convert HttpPostedFileBase to HttpPostedFile

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately tvanfosson's answer did not work for me. Although the files would upload just fine, and no error would be thrown, a problem would occur where only one of the files would be used, so the same file would be saved twice rather than using them both.

It seemed to be a problem with the foreach statement looping through the names of each file in the Request.Files, for some reason it wasn't working as a key for me, and only the first file would be selected every time.

```
HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;

for(var i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];

    ...
}
```

Comment: This was a problem for us on iOS because the "take photo" feature names every file "image.jpg" - but this change resolved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The following code worked for me.

```
  HttpResponseMessage result = null;
  var httpRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
  HttpFileCollection uploadFiles = httpRequest.Files;
  var docfiles = new List<string>();

  if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0){
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < uploadFiles.Count; i++) {
          HttpPostedFile postedFile = uploadFiles[i];
          var filePath = @"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/test1/reports/" + postedFile.FileName;
          postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
          docfiles.Add(filePath);
      }
      result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, docfiles);
  } else {
      result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `HttpPostedFile` out of the `HttpFileCollection` using `foreach` like this:

```
foreach (var obj in fileCollection)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = fileCollection.Get(obj.ToString());
}
```