# Get all files from Request.Files with same Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, collections, model-binding

I have some files with the same keys in **Request.Files** object and when I use this code **Request.Files.Keys["keyName"]** it returns just one file but I have more than one file with that key. what should I do?!
By the way I can't use key names as argument because I don't know what key exactly is, maybe model binder can help in this case but I don't know how can I use it for Files.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760510/foreach-on-request-files

Answer (score 10):

you try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    if (Request.Files.GetKey(i) == "keyName")
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload = Request.Files.Get(i);
    }
}
```