# Handling files from two file inputs

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webforms, generic-handler

I have the following `HTML` code:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Your photo file</td>
    <td ><input id="EmpSelfPhoto" type="file" /></td>
    <td style='color:red'>Not requiered</td>
    </tr>
  
   <tr>
    <td>Your CV file</td>
    <td><input id="EmpCV" type="file" /></td>
     <td style='color:red'>Requiered</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input id="PostFile" type="button" value="Upload .." /></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

And I'm using `Jquery ajax -generic handler` to upload the posted files.
The problem is `context.Request.Files.Count` will validate for all inputs and I have to loop throw all input using `HttpFileCollection`.

---

**How can I validate each file input separately in server side?** For example *I would like to check if file input 1 has file, and check if file input 2 is a valid picture.*

Comment: The enumerator for the HttpFileCollection gives you the names given to each HTML input control. You should give each input a unique name attribute. See [this SO page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760510/foreach-on-request-files) on the topic.

Comment: @DanWilson i couldn't  handle HttpPostedFileBase, i'm using webforms btw..